# Creating animated progress bar

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a animated input/progress bar, but just the untracked part must be animated.

```css
@keyframes gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
}

#loading input {
  background-size: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab); //just random colors as example
  animation: gradient 5s ease infinite;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="loading">
  <input id="progress" type='range' min="0" max="100" step="0.01" value="0">
</div>
```

The problem is that I have no idea about how I can make the untracked area animated. Could you please help me fix this?

[image: untracked part must be animate]

Comment: `input[type="range"]` elements and `progress` elements are different. From your code, we can assume you're talking about `input[type="range"]` and **not** a `progress` element. Am afraid that, those type of inputs do not respect (ignore) the styles you're applying.

Comment: With which of the two is it possible for me to do what I want?

Comment: That depends on your case, `progress` elements do not have the ability of changing the value like range `input`s do. I think you'll need to build you're own progress bar with the desired appearance.

Comment: Do you want a bootstrap like [progress bar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/progress/#animated-stripes) only the not completed part should be animated?

Comment: @ITgoldman yes, something like this!!

Comment: Is this a genuine input, ie the user will change the value, or will the value be changed gradually eg by JS?

Comment: Only the user will be able to change the value @AHaworth